# data is not inserted (in database ) for unknown reason in my website server

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I was trying to convert a form of ajax insert, delete , edit system to  my own . Its working nicely in localhost . But whenever I am trying to run these code in my website server , insertion is not working ( delete and edit is working ) . My codes are :

```
<div class="container box">
        <h1 align="center">PHP PDO Ajax CRUD </h1>
        <br />
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <br />
            <div align="right">
                <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" 
  class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add</button>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="10%">Image</th>
                        <th width="30%"> Name</th>
                        <th width="30%">Education</th>
                        <th width="10%">age</th>
                        <th width="10%">Edit</th>
                        <th width="10%">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            
        </div>
    </div>
     

   </body>
 </html>

 <div id="userModal" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <form method="post" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label>Enter First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
                <br />
                <label>Enter Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="education" id="education" class="form-control" />
                <br />
                <label>Enter Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />
                <br />
                <label>Select User Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />
                <span id="user_uploaded_image"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />
                <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
 </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_button').click(function(){
    $('#user_form')[0].reset();
    $('.modal-title').text("Add User");
    $('#action').val("Add");
    $('#operation').val("Add");
    $('#user_uploaded_image').html('');
});

var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing":true,
    "serverSide":true,
    "order":[],
    "ajax":{
        url:"fetch.php",
        type:"POST"
    },
    "columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets":[0, 3, 4],
            "orderable":false,
        },
    ],

});

$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name= $('#name').val();
    var education= $('#education').val();
    var age= $('#age').val();
    var extension = $('#user_image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if(extension != '')
    {
        if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
        {
            alert("Invalid Image File");
            $('#user_image').val('');
            return false;
        }
    }   
    if(name!= '' && education!= '' && age!= '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:'POST',
            data:new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                $('#userModal').modal('hide');
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Both Fields are Required");
    }
});
```

the code in insert.php are : (I am just showing the code instead maintaining proper way of using brackets , so that we can be right at the point )

```
<?php
 include('db.php');
 include('function.php');
  if(isset($_POST["operation"]))
   {
     if($_POST["operation"] == "Add")
    {
       $image = '';
        if($_FILES["user_image"]["name"] != '')
       {
           $image = upload_image();
       }
       $statement = $connection->prepare("
           INSERT INTO new_table (name, education, age, image) 
           VALUES (:name, :education, :age, :image)
        ");
        $result = $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':name' =>  $_POST["name"],
            ':education'    =>  $_POST["education"],
            ':age'  =>  $_POST["age"],
            ':image'        =>  $image
        )
    );
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    }
}
?>
```

The result after submission appears as bellow :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqamS.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  `is not working` is not a problem description.  Please describe what happens, and what you expected.  Do you see any errors?  Have you done some basic debugging with your browser's devtools?  You should be able to find out quite a lot more info about the problem by inspecting the console and network requests.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion sir, the problem is whenever i am clicking the add button, the alert appears blank instead saying inserted ,  data is not inserted in database as well . It works nicely in localhost though . ( I am not much good in  json/ ajax )

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Use your browser's devtools. If you're not sure what that means do some research, eg here is the general info about Chrome's (but each browser has similar): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: it's showing "no error"  in console ,

Answer (score 1):

You're refering to `$_POST['operation']` in your AJAX code but is has no value defined in HTML, try replacing :

```
<input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" />
<input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />
```

by

```
<input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" value="Add" />
<input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" />
```

Comment: the value of $_POST['operation'] is defined here i guess :    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_button').click(function(){
    $('#user_form')[0].reset();
    $('.modal-title').text("Add User");
    $('#action').val("Add");
    $('#operation').val("Add");
    $('#user_uploaded_image').html('');
});

Comment: I have tried your suggestion too, but the result is same , i have edited the screen shot of my result above

Comment: Your blank alert is your `alert(data);` most probably. Which means your PHP code does not echo anything. By the way, don't you have a syntax error in `insert.php` ? Seems to me that you open one more curly brace than you close, no ?

Comment: I don't have any syntax error, funny thing is, I copied and ran the same code in localhost and it's working perfectly here, but giving blank alert in website server

Comment: This would mean you have a mismatch between the number of token you bind in your execute query and the number of tokens you have in your prepared statement, but here I see 4 in both cases. Is line 22 the  `$result = $statement->execute(/*[...]*/);` ?

Comment: I am sorry for that comment sir, that error was not a recent one , I am getting no error right now ,but it's kept giving blank alert  and no data is inserted to database